# why the datePicker appears very thin?

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker

I want to know why the UIDatePicker appears very thin? I am using this code:

```
 datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];

 datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;

 [datePicker setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr"] ];

 NSDate *tomorrow = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(24*60*60) sinceDate:[NSDate date]];

 [datePicker setDate:tomorrow];

 [datePicker setMinimumDate:tomorrow];

 [_dateField setInputView:datePicker];
```

After Execution of this code, I have this result :

[image]

As you can see the UIDatePicker appears very thin, not like the usual appearance.

Comment: What do you mean by "very thin"?

Comment: i mean that the datePicker does not appear normally .
the font size of the rows ( dates ) is very low I think

Answer (score 0):

This is just because of new them of IOS.
Hear you need to set the custom background color
also you can set the height using its delegate method

[pickerViewPtr setDataSource: self];

Add the below method to you class where you implemented the picker view
// to resize the row height
**- (CGSize)rowSizeForComponent:(NSInteger)component;**

And  also

// returns the view provided by the delegate via pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:
// or nil if the row/component is not visible or the delegate does not implement 
// pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:
**- (nullable UIView *)viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;**

Also you have the control to manipulate the text

- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
  {
  NSString *title = @"sample title";
  NSAttributedString *attString = 
      [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];

  return attString;
  }

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason why the datepicker appears with this font size (not normal font size)
in fact in the application there is this method redefined :

> - (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize ;

which makes the datepicker appears with the font size defined in this method.

anyway thank you for your help.